# Rounding decimal number upto two decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, rounding

I am trying to round decimal number upto two decimal places which is working perfectly.
I am doing as below :

```
Math.Round(Amount, 2)
```

So, if I have Amount as `40000.4567`, I am getting `40000.46`which is exactly what I want.
Now problem is I have decimal number like `40000.0000`, when I round it, the result is `40000`, and what I really want is `40000.00`. So round will always neglect trailing zeros.

To solve this problem, I have the option of converting it to string and use format , but I don't want to do that as that will be inefficient and I believe there must be some way to do it better.

I also tried something like

```
Decimal.Round(Amount, 2)
```

Now one way can be to check whether number contains anything in fractional part and use round function accordingly , but that is really bad way to do it.
I can't use truncate as well due to obvious reasons of this being related to amount.

What is the way around?

Comment: what is the difference between 4000 and 4000.00 ? These are the same decimals - what you want is string formatting

Comment: if you want string result, One hardcode, after rounding, convert to int if the converted to int value and rounded value the same than add to end ",00"

Comment: Well from the client perspective, I can't show some figures as for example 40000 and some which will be rounded like 45666.23, that won't seem consistent in presentation layer. I can do it by string formatting, but why use that overhead, is there not a way to do it using mathematical functions!

Comment: @Jamaxack I don't need string result, but then if I can't do it , I will have to first convert it to string, format it , and convert back, that seems pretty bad way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* rounding correctly but you fail to understand that the *value* is not the *format.* There is no *difference* between the two values, `40000` and `40000.00`, and you'll have a similar issue with something like `3.1`.

Simply use formatting to output whatever number you have to two decimal places, such as with:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", value));
```

or:

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: I know value is not format, that is why I said is there not a way to for example round a decimal and keep optional 2 trailing zeros in after decimal if it doesn't contain anything in fractional part without using string format

Comment: @ubaid, no there is not, because of the value/format dichotomy.

Comment: So , in other words, I will need to convert decimal number to string every time i need to format it, don't know why, but I don't feel it is a good thing

Comment: @ubaid, no, it's really _not_ a bad thing. The alternative of course is not having formatted numbers, which is probably worse.

Comment: @ubaid, if you're displaying the number to the client, then you're converting it to a string anyway. If you're not displaying it, then you don't need to format it.

Comment: @paxdiablo, it may be worth mentioning that you don't have to use `string.Format`: `value.ToString("0.00")` works too.

Comment: I did same now @SimonMᶜKenzie

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things - rounding and output formatting. In order to output a number in a format you want you can use function `string.Format` with required format, for example:

```
decimal number = 1234.567m;
string.Format("{0:#.00}", number);
```

You can read more about [custom numeric format strings in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is displaying two decimals, even if they are zero. You can use string.Format for this (I've also combined it with Round):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", Math.Round(Amount, 2));
```

Comment: You may want to add some details about the difference between using just `string.Format` and using it in combination with `Math.Round`, i.e. that `string.Format`'s `0` specifier will [round away from zero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), while `Math.Round`'s default rounding is [to the nearest even number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

for rounding decimal number you can use

```
decimal number=200.5555m;
number= Math.Round(number, 2);
string numString= string.Format("{0:0.00}", number);
```