# Visual Basic passing the contents of one variable from one sub to another sub and round to d.p

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a sub that works out a quadratic equation after inputting 3 coefficients.

However, I have to round that answer to whatever the user wishes to between 1 decimal point to 5.

```
Module Module1
Public property MyAnswer As Object
Sub myQuadraticEquation()
... 'enter 3 coefficients
Dim d As Integer = b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c 
    Console.Write("Your roots are: ")
    MyResult = (((-b + d) / (2 * a) & " , " & (-b - d) / (2 * a)))
    Console.WriteLine(MyAnswer)
End Module
```

My question is, how can I round the answer from this mathematical feature to a certain amount of d.p based on users' liking?

Can I create another sub and then call it later using if statement inside the Quadratic equation?

It's giving me the following error

> "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Your quadratic equation should stay the same unless you pass a 4th parameter that is the rounding precision. If you don't pass a parameter, take the result and [round it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) after.

Comment: @the_lotus but how would I do that? I'm quite knew to all of this.

Comment: @the_lotus I have tried the following, but it's giving me an error:
' Console.WriteLine(Round(Convert.ToDecimal(MyResult), 2)) '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding decimal number upto two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847216/rounding-decimal-number-upto-two-decimal-places)

Comment: "it's giving me an error". What error? We are not psychic.

Comment: OK, I see part of your issue. You are concatenating two numbers and making a string. You are trying to round a string which....doesn't work. I also suggest turning Option Explicit On so you are forced to declare your variables and data types, which is best practice anyways. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement

Comment: It's saying: "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
@Jeremy
So I believe you are right, but how can I avoid turning this into a string then?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest always declaring variables as the datatype you want instead of relying on the program to figure them out at runtime. So change `Public property MyAnswer As Object` to `Public property MyAnswer As String`. Because you know you expect `MyAnswer` to be a string at the end.

As far as the rounding is concerned, I believe you were attempting to do it too late. I would change

```
MyAnswer = (((-b + d) / (2 * a) & " , " & (-b - d) / (2 * a)))
```

to

```
Dim part1 As Decimal = Math.Round((-b + d) / (2 * a), DigitsToRound)
Dim part2 As Decimal = Math.Round((-b - d) / (2 * a), DigitsToRound)
'This line can be simplified, look up string interpolation if you are using  VS 2017
MyAnswer = part1 & " , " & part2
```

Where `DigitsToRound` is indicated by the user somehow. A bit more code and it technically can be simplified down quite a bit but I was trying to be as explicit as possible.

**Edit:

Just realized there is a name discrepancy in your code. I'm assuming you meant `MyAnswer` instead of `MyResult` in the code snippet you posted. If I am mistaken then I apoligize.

** Edit #2:

> How can I transfer the contents of these variables into another sub, so that when I call this other sub I'm able to round it to whatever d.p I want it to. e.g. 'would you like this into 3.d.p'... then it should output the answer in 3dp. I've tried to do it, but I tend to get 0 as an output

using a separate function for this seems like a bit of overkill but it could look something like this:

```
Public Function DoRounding(ByVal p_value as Decimal) as Decimal 
    Dim ret As Decimal = 0D
    Dim DigitsToRound As Integer = 0
    'This line prompts the user for input and attempts to parse the input into an integer field named DigitsToRound. 
    'If the parsing fails then whatever the user typed in was not an integer and we tell them we are unable to proceed. Default input is 1.
    If Integer.TryParse(InputBox("How many digits would you like to round to?", "Decimal Places", 1), DigitsToRound) Then
        ret = Math.Round(p_value, DigitsToRound)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input Detected")
    End If
    Return ret
End Function
```

This would prompt the user every time the function was called which could be pretty annoying. It would be better to prompt them once and then pass the value that they enter around to whatever functions need it.

Comment: Thank you! @Mike_OBrien
It makes sense. I just have one last question. How can I transfer the contents of these variables into another sub, so that when I call this other sub I'm able to round it to whatever d.p I want it to. e.g. 'would you like this into 3.d.p'... then it should output the answer in 3dp. I've tried to do it, but I tend to get 0 as an output.